# some mistakes on creating application

Tags: android

I'm learning how to create app with android studio, 
this is my code source:

```
 package com.example.droide;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DroideSphereRuhlmannActivity extends Activity implements      OnClickListener {
    private TextView logview;
    private Button connect, deconnect;
    private ImageView forwardArrow, backArrow, rightArrow, leftArrow, stop, topleftArrow, toprightArrow, backleftArrow, backrightArrow;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private String[] logArray = null;
    private BtInterface bt = null;

    static final String TAG = "Droid";
    static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String data = msg.getData().getString("receivedData");
            addToLog(data);
        }
    };

    final Handler handlerStatus = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int status = msg.arg1;
            if(status == BtInterface.CONNECTED) {
                addToLog("Connected");
            } else if(status == BtInterface.DISCONNECTED) {
                addToLog("Disconnected");
            }
        }
    };

    private void addToLog(String message){
        for (int i = 1; i < logArray.length; i++){
            logArray[i-1] = logArray[i];
        }
        logArray[logArray.length - 1] = message;

        logview.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < logArray.length; i++){
            if (logArray[i] != null){
                logview.append(logArray[i] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_remote);
        logview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logview);
        logArray = new String[3];
        connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        connect.setOnClickListener(this);
        deconnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deconnect);
        deconnect.setOnClickListener(this);
        forwardArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.forward_arrow);
        forwardArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        backArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        backArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.right_arrow);
        rightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        leftArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.left_arrow);
        leftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        topleftArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.topleft_arrow);
        topleftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        toprightArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.topright_arrow);
        toprightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        backrightArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backright_arrow);
        backrightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        backleftArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backleft_arrow);
        backrightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Device does not support Bluetooth");
        }
        else{
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){

                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            else{
                bt = new BtInterface(handlerStatus, handler);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent moreData){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                bt = new BtInterface(handlerStatus, handler);
            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                Log.v(TAG, "BT pas active");
            else
                Log.v(TAG, "code n'est pas valide");
        }
        else{
            Log.v(TAG, "code n'est pas reconnu");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == connect) {
            addToLog("Appareillage en cours");
            bt.connect();
        }
        else if(v == deconnect) {
            addToLog("connexion en cours");
            bt.close();
        }
        else if(v == forwardArrow) {
            bt.sendData("F");
        }
        else if(v == backArrow) {
            bt.sendData("B");
        }
        else if(v == rightArrow) {
            bt.sendData("R");
        }
        else if(v == leftArrow) {
            bt.sendData("L");
        }
        else if( v == topleftArrow){
            bt.sendData("I");
        }
        else if(v == toprightArrow){``
            bt.sendData("J");
        }
        else if(v == backleftArrow){
            bt.sendData("G");
        }
        else if(v ==backrightArrow){
            bt.sendData("H");
        }
        else if(v == stop) {
            bt.sendData("S");
        }
```

Error Log:

After that, I got some error like :

> "Error:(156, 10) error: reached end of file while parsing"

or

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'."

So now I don't now how to solve that.

Comment: Please show us the exact error message and which line of chuffed causes it.

Comment: Your code is missing some curly braces at the end. I suggest you learn some Java basics and start with a simpler app.

Comment: i think the same things but i don't know there can i add theses curly braces

Comment: The line after each open brace should be indented. Every closing brace should be dedented to the same level as the matching opening brace. Format your code according to these rules and the missing braces will be obvious.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your full code then your onClick method has not ending curly bracket and also your main class is not ended with curly bracket.

so add two ending curly braces at end of your code